# Hide/Show content with many variables

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to reveal/hide content on a click event as follows:

```
$('#staffer1').click(function() {
    $("#staff1").show();
    $("#staff2").hide();
    $("#staff3").hide();
});     

$('#staffer2').click(function() {
    $("#staff2").show();
    $("#staff1").hide();
    $("#staff3").hide();
}); 

$('#staffer3').click(function() {
    $("#staff3").show();
    $("#staff1").hide();
    $("#staff2").hide();    
});
```

This issue lies in volume. If we have 60 staffers, is there a way to circumvent listing out 60 lines for each click event?

HTML is like so:

```
<div>
<p><a id="staffer1">Staff Name 1</a></p>
<p><a id="staffer2">Staff Name 2</a></p>
<p><a id="staffer3">Staff Name 3</a></p>
</div>

<div id="staff1">
<div class="slider">
<img src="image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="staff_bio">
<p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugi.</p>
</div>
</div>  

<div id="staff2">
<div class="slider">
<img src="image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="staff_bio">
<p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugi.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: give each staffer a class, then use that class to toggle show() and hide()

Comment: This depends on how the markup looks, post some HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class called `staff` to each staff element and then use that to hide all the others:

```
$('#staffer1').click(function() {
    $(".staff").hide();
    $("#staff1").show();
});
```

Even better, have a `staffer` class as well and then you can have a single handler for everything:

```
$('.staffer').click(function() {
    $(".staff").hide();
    var num = $(this).attr(id).replace(/staffer/, '');
    $("#staff"+num).show();
});
```

I don't know what your html looks like, but there are other ways you can do it as well, such as using `data-` and `.data()` to store/retrieve the staff number:

http://jsfiddle.net/hcvWQ/

Using `.index()` to figure out which `.staffer` was clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmXqx/

Or, just using html structure to associate the link/button with the info, as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kde9J/

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Jeff B. You should add a class to each HTML element and you should use jQuery to attach the function to the elements.

I strongly recommend http://jqueryui.com/ rather than inventing your own UI and interactions.

Here's a functional fiddle from your recent HTML edit. 

http://jsfiddle.net/krets/VgrTE/

Just add the classes as Jeff B suggested.

```
<p><a id="staffer1" class="staffer">Staff Name 1</a></p>
...
<div id="staff1" class="staff">
...

$(function() {
    $('.staffer').each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.staff').hide()
            var num = $(this).attr("id").replace(/staffer/, '');
            $("#staff"+num).show()
        });
    });
});
```